# Не открывается iFrame в приложении на Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, ios, iframe, cordova

Доброе время суток. Есть планшетное приложение, написанное с помощью JS, HTML, CSS на платформе [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/). Не открывает iFrame на самом девайсе. Нет никакой ошибки, доступ ко всем доменам открыт `<access origin="*" />`. На десктопе все работает нормально. Пробовал вставлять iframe через js, безрезультатно. Может кто сталкивался? Может ли [InAppBrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/ru/3.1.0/cordova/inappbrowser/inappbrowser.html) открывать ссылку в frame ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло добавление `<allow-navigation href="*" />`

Answer (score 0):

Сильно зависит от того, что открываете в iframe:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/iFrame-Usage

Может помочь вот это:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Что-то из этого:

`<access origin="*" />`

`<!-- Allow iframe to https://cordova.apache.org/ -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' https://cordova.apache.org">`